# Behavior of CN.getProperty("AppArg", null); on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I have a doubt about `String arg = CN.getProperty("AppArg", null);` on iOS.

This is the behavior on Android: once you receive an "arg" (by intercepting a link), if the app switches from foreground to background and then back to foreground, the string "arg" is equal to null. This is the expected and desired behavior.

On iOS, switching from foreground to background and then back to foreground, the value of "arg" remains the same. This is not a desired behavior, this way it is as if the last link is intercepted again every time the app switches to foreground.

Fortunately, I found a very simple workaround, compatible with both Android and iOS:

```
    public void start() {
        // check if a link starting with mycoolapp:// was intercepted
        String arg = getProperty("AppArg", null);
        setProperty("AppArg", null);
        if (arg != null) {
            LinkInterceptor interceptor = new LinkInterceptor(arg);
            if (interceptor.isKnown()) {
                interceptor.execute();
                return;
            }
        }

        if (current != null) {
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World", BoxLayout.y());
        hi.add(new Label("Hi World"));
        hi.show();
    }
```

The trick is the line `setProperty("AppArg", null);`.

Is this behavior a bug or an iOS feature?

Comment: I'm guessing this is a bug but some customer might depend on this bug so please file an issue. Either way it's good to have an issue on that for people searching on this.